# Unable to find center of view?

Tags: android

I am trying to find the center child but everytime I execute the check below,the else part gets executed,I don't know why...Oh and by the way I am trying to edit 3dcoursel

```
 if (childCenter >= galleryCenter)///check if the image is in the centre 
        {Log.i("HOLA///", " you are awesome");
        }   
     else {
            Log.i("HOLA///", " you too are awesome ");
     }






galleryCenter = getCenterOfGallery();
childCenter = getCenterOfView(child);



  private static int getCenterOfView(View view) {
        return view.getLeft() + view.getWidth() / 2;
    }   




 private int getCenterOfGallery() {
        return (getWidth() - Carousel.this.getPaddingLeft() - Carousel.this.getPaddingRight()) / 2 + 
            Carousel.this.getPaddingLeft();
    }
```

Comment: og.i("HOLA///", " you are awesome"); you are missing the L here...

Comment: it was a typo ...not a solution by the way thanx